No handle of webhook POST req despite receiving OK POST req from Stripe in CLI - NextJS 14
I am receiving correctly Stripe webhooks POST req but having trouble handling the request.
Is there something I am missing? Console.logs don't print to terminal.
Here is my code so far with the outline of what i want to handle when received checkout.session.completed from stripe.
./api/webhook/route.ts
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { Resend } from 'resend';
import EmailTemplate from '@/components/email-template';


const resend = new Resend(process.env.NEXT_RESEND_API_KEY);

const supabase = createClient(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!
);

const stripe = new Stripe(`${process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`, {
  apiVersion: '2023-08-16',
});

//Handling incoming POST req
async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const body = await request.text();
    const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_WEBHOOK_KEY!;
    const sig = headers().get('stripe-signature') as string;
    // const sig = headers().get('Stripe-Signature') as string;
    let event: Stripe.Event;
    //read the event data from stripe
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      return new Response(`Webhook Error: ${err}`, {
        status: 400,
      });
    }
    console.log(`Received event !webhook!: ${event?.type}`);
    // Handle the event: checkout.session.completed
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'checkout.session.completed':
        const session: any = event.data.object;
        console.log('!Checkout session completed!:', session.payment_status);

        // get customer name, email
        const customerEmail = session.customer_details.email;
        const customerName = session.customer_details.name;

        // create the customer in db
        const { data: customer, error: errorCustomer } = await supabase
          .from('Customer')
          .insert({ customerName, customerEmail })
          .select()
          .single();

        if (errorCustomer) throw new Error(errorCustomer.message);

       
        break;
      default:
    }
    return NextResponse.json({ received: true });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error }, { status: 400 });
  }
}

async function GET(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) {
  // Bad Request or how ever you want to respond.
  return response.status(400).json({ error: 'Bad Request' });
}

export { POST, GET };


Thank you in advance.
Stripe CLI post request webhooks are received - OK.

checkout.session.completed is received  - OK
checkout.session.completed triggers supabase and further actions which are not happening despite correct POST reponses.

I'm sorry but it's not clear to me what parts of this code are and are not being triggered.  If you add a console.log('foo') line immediately inside the function POST block, do you see it logged?

Hi @RyanM, no part of the code is being triggered not even if when i added as you said the console.log(''foo').
I can share with you that i am getting correct CLI POST reqs, I added that to my post.

I was listening to wrong route.
Incorrect:
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/checkout

Correct:
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhook

